# Neural Networks : designing Cost function "not differentiable" / Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am testing the Tensorflow framework with a regression problem. My input has many features and my output only one. 
For now, it is working but I think that my Cost function is not accurate for what I want, so I have pretty low accuracy.

My goal is to predict the output within a 10% range of the actual output, that is to say for each output  :

```
if (y_actual - y_predicted) < 0.1 * y_actual :
    cost = 0
else :
    cost = 1
```

So for a predicted output vector of :
`[130, 35, 65, 43]` vs an actual output vector of `[125, 10, 75, 40]`, I should get a cost of 2. (130 and 40 are in the 10%, 35 and 65 are not)

For now, I use a squared difference.

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(y_predicted,y_)/(2*nb_batches))
```

So actually, I get a pretty good prediction for the sum of the outputs but I only have a 60% accuracy if I consider a prediction to be accurate if it is in the 10% of the actual output. 
My accuracy is written like that :

```
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
        correct_prediction = tf.less_equal(tf.abs((y_predicted-y_)), 0.1*tf.abs((y_))) # True if y_diff <= 10% * y_actual
    with tf.name_scope('accuracy'): 
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)) # count 1 if correct prediction is True ; else False ; Do the sum on all the data tested
    tf.scalar_summary('accuracy', accuracy)
```

I tried to write other cost functions such as :

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((tf.greater_equal(tf.abs((y_predicted-y_)), 0.1*tf.abs(y_))),tf.float32)
```

But I get the error : `No gradients provided for any variable`. I think that it is because we cannot get the derivative of `tf.cast`.

Is there a proper way to write a loss function that would fit my needs?
I know that the loss function I want is not "derivable". Do you think that transforming it to a derivable function would be a solution ?

I am not sure I was very clear...

Thanks for your help !

Paul

Comment: I think the error occurs when there is no path from your variables to loss function. Could be a possible bug in your graph definition.

Comment: Yes, I think that with tf.cast, Tensorflow is not able to get back to the variables... But as the cost needs to be a float...

Comment: Did you happen to find a work around for `tf.cast`?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the comparison operator, you could use
`tf.nn.relu(tf.abs(y_predicted-y_)-tf.abs(y_))`
to get a differentiable cost function.

The relu operation compute max(0, x) and thus will give a continuous version of what you were doing. The main difference will be that you will be more penalized for being farther away and thus you don't have the binary property (but this is usually what you aim for in regression).
This should yield better result than the squared loss.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I think there is just a typo : I think it should be
tf.nn.relu(tf.abs(y_predicted-y_)- 0.1*tf.abs(y_))

As you said though, one error of "27" would be counted as 27 errors of "1" while for the accuracy it is not the case.

Comment: Actually, I got an accuracy which was smaller than when I used the squared loss... A possibility would be to "count" the number of not-null values but I don't know any TF function that does that and testing np.count_nonzero, it is not working. 

Also, I was wondering whether using the error function, i.e. Erf(alpha*x) would be a good fit...